# How to use Data Pump utilities without a tnsnames.ora file

Tags: oracle, command-line, tnsnames, datapump

I want to be able to run `expdp` and `impdp` by directly specifying the connection parameters instead of a TNS name that resides in `tnsnames.ora`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may be able to specify it all on the command line with a Connection String instead of a TNSName. Remove the whitespace from your TNS entry you would have used to connect, here is an example that works with SQLPLUS...

Here is how to connect to a local OracleXE install on Windows:

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=xe)))
```

On *Nix you may need to quote the entry so the parens aren't interpreted incorrectly:

```
sqlplus 'scott/tiger@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=xe)))'
```

Comment: While this works as given for `sqlplus`, it does not seem to work for `expdp` - I'm getting `LRM-00116: syntax error at 'ADDRESS_LIST' following '('` using Oracle 12.1.0.2.0.

Answer (score 5):

You might try an [EZCONNECT string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle):

```
expdp userid=user/pw@//host:port/service-name
```

You will need a sqlnet.ora parameter on the client side that includes EZCONNECT, e.g.:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

Comment: This works great! Note that the `//` is optional. Also, I didn't need to configure anything on the client side for it to work.